# Why the full $r$-torsion group contains $r^2$ many elements and consists of $r+1$ subgroups

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings

let $F$ be a finite field, $E(F)$ an elliptic curve of order $n$, $r$ a factor of $n$,  $k(r)$ for the embedding degree of $E(F)$ with respect to $r$.

Then why the full $r$-torsion group contains $r^2$ many elements and consists of $r+1$ subgroups?

Answer (score 1):

Only if $r$ is prime.

Let $E[r] = \langle P,Q \rangle$ be the $r$-torsion subgroup. Its cyclic subgroup is defined by a generator of the form $[a]P + [b]Q$, but up to a (non-zero) scalar multiple: because $G$ and $[k]G$ generate the same subgroups.

How to count the subgroups? In the expression
$$G = [a]P + [b]Q$$ we can always take $$[a^{-1}]G = [1]P + [ba^{-1}]Q$$ if $a$ is nonzero, or $$[b^{-1}]G = [ab^{-1}]P + [1]Q$$ if $b$ is nonzero (and one of them has to be non-zero).

Therefore, we can count $2r$ generators of the form $[1]P + [a]Q$ and $[a]P + [1]Q$ for any $a$ (incl. 0). But we counted the subgroups where both coefficients are invertible twice, which is when $a$ is invertible (non-zero):
$$\langle[1]P+[a][Q]\rangle=\langle[a^{-1}]P+[1][Q]\rangle.$$
So we have to correct it and get $$2r-(r-1)=r+1.$$

Comment: This answer missing the title part.